# python regular expression across multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm gathering some info from some cisco devices using python and pexpect, and had a lot of success with REs to extract pesky little items. I'm afraid i've hit the wall on this. Some switches stack together, I have identified this in the script and used a separate routine to parse the data. If the switch is stacked you see the following (extracted from the sho ver output)

```
Top Assembly Part Number        : 800-25858-06
Top Assembly Revision Number    : A0
Version ID                      : V08
CLEI Code Number                : COMDE10BRA
Hardware Board Revision Number  : 0x01


Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------
*    1   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M  
     2   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     3   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     4   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M


Switch 02 
---------
Switch Uptime                   : 11 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 27 minutes
Base ethernet MAC Address       : 00:26:52:96:2A:80
Motherboard assembly number     : 73-9675-15
```

When I encounter this I need to extract the switch number & model for each in the table of 4, (sw can be ignored, but there can be between 1 and 9 switches) It's the multiple line thing that has got me as I've been ok with the rest. Any ideas please?

OK apologies. My regex simply started looking at the last group of - until.. then I couldn't work ou where to go!
    -{10]\s-{10}(.+)Switch

The model will change and the number of switches will change, I need to capture the 4 lines in this example which are

```
*    1   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M  
     2   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     3   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     4   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
```

But each switch could be a different model and there could be between 1 and 9. For this example ideally i'd like to get

```
*,1,WS-C3750-48P
,2,WS-C3750-48P
,3,WS-C3750-48P
,4,WS-C3750-48P
```

(the asterisk means master)
but getting those lines would set me on the right track

Comment: how about you post the current regex code you tried... i'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x="""Top Assembly Part Number        : 800-25858-06
Top Assembly Revision Number    : A0
Version ID                      : V08
CLEI Code Number                : COMDE10BRA
Hardware Board Revision Number  : 0x01


Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------
*    1   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     2   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     3   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
     4   52     WS-C3750-48P       12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M


Switch 02
---------
Switch Uptime                   : 11 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 27 minutes
Base ethernet MAC Address       : 00:26:52:96:2A:80
Motherboard assembly number     : 73-9675-15"""

>>> import re
>>> re.findall("^\*?\s*(\d)\s*\d+\s*([A-Z\d-]+)",x,re.MULTILINE)
[('1', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('2', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('3', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('4', 'WS-C3750-48P')]
```

**UPDATE**: because OP edited question, and Thanks Tom for pointing out for +

```
>>> re.findall("^(\*?)\s+(\d)\s+\d+\s+([A-Z\d-]+)",x,re.MULTILINE)
[('*', '1', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('', '2', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('', '3', 'WS-C3750-48P'), ('', '4', 'WS-C3750-48P')]
>>>
```

Comment: +1 because I think you did a fine job of answering the question quickly :-). But to clean this up... I would use \s+ instead of \s*. Also, re.MULTILINE does nothing of importance in this case. I believe your solution will work without it :-).

Comment: @Tom, well, you need the multi-line IF that `^` is to match the start-of-line, as I elaborated on in my answer -- I'm just not sure whether it's actually necessary to sync up with start-of-line, it depends on how the "model" can be identified.

Comment: Hmm what you do above looks ok but you are only parsing the table. The string you are using is in the middle of a whole bunch of other text (see original post) with the table in the middle. My data has maybe 50 lines above and below

Comment: BTW model will always start WS-

Comment: OK, I was not sure it always starts with WS-, going to update it.

Comment: Ah, It will be exact same with Alex Answer, So I won't update it, instead please accept Alex Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

To have `.` match any character, including a newline, compile your RE with [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re.dotall#re.DOTALL) among the options (remember, if you have multiple options, use `|`, the bit-or operator, between them, in order to combine them).

In this case I'm not sure you actually do need this -- why not something like

```
re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+\d+\s+(WS-\S+)')
```

assuming for example that the way you identify a "model" is that it starts with `WS-`?  The fact that there will be newlines between one result of `findall` and the next one is not a problem here.  Can you explain exactly how you identify a "model" and why "multiline" is an issue?  Maybe you want the [re.MULTILINE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re.dotall#re.MULTILINE) to make `^` match at each start-of-line, to grab your data with some reference to the start of the lines...?

Comment: Alex, once again, you beat me to it :-). The key to doing multiline regexes is really the re.DOTALL (which is confusing because you would think it's re.MULTILINE). BUT, as he pointed out you don't need it in this case since your data you want to extract is on its own line :-). Also, I like that alex used \s+, meaning 1 or more whitespace character. Also, one thing I might have added... I usually like to name my groups: (?P<model>WS-\S+).

Comment: Hmm you are probably right there - will try that and report back, but as I'm UK it will be tomorrow. Many thanks for your time