# How to ignore \n in regular expressions in python?

Tags: python

So i have a regex telling if a number is integer.

`regex = '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$'`

```
import re
bool(re.search(regex, '42\n'))
```

returns True, and it is not supposed to?
Where does the problem come from ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python regular expression across multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870954/python-regular-expression-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: Totally don't get what stays there.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that. The solution is different. Plus, that question isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `'$'`
>
> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string

Try `\Z` instead.

Also, any time you find yourself writing a regular expression that starts with `^` or `\A` and ends with `$` or `\Z`, if your intent is to only match the entire string, you should probably use `re.fullmatch()` instead of `re.search()` (and omit the boundary markers from the regex). Or if you're using a version of Python that's too old to have `re.fullmatch()`, (you really need to upgrade but) you can use `re.match()` and omit the beginning-of-string boundary marker.

Answer (score 0):

regex ahould be `regex = '\b^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$\b'`

Answer (score 0):

The regex in the question matches ->start of line, numbers and end of line. And the given string matches that, thats why it is returning true. If you want it to return False when there is a number present, you can use "!" to indicate NOT.

Refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
regex = '!(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$'
bool(re.search(regex, '42\n')) => (Returns false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that $ matching one \n before the end is kind of trap/inconsistency. Check out my list of regex traps for python: http://www.cofoh.com/advanced-regex-tutorial-python/traps

Comment: This link is dead