# Read a floating point matrix using Regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to read a matrix from a file using RegEx. The file consists of several strng, \n characteres, white spaces and floating point numbers. I would like to read *only* sets of three or more consecutive floating points. An exemple of code is as follow:

Data.txt

```
$Nodes
5
1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0
3 1 1 0
4 0 1 0
5 0.5 0.5 0
$EndNodes
$Values
5
1 1.5 3.6
2 1.5 3.4
3 1.5 3.3
4 1.5 3.5
5 1.5 3.1
$EndValues
```

In my read_file.py, I have:

```
def read_file(filename):
    text = str()
    with open(filename) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            text += line
    return text
```

The final output of my read_file functions is a big string containing the whole text, so I could use RegEx to find whatever I like all at once.
Well, I would like to read all the sets of three numbers (After $Nodes\n5 and before $EndNodes\n).

I tried many things, like `re.compile(r'\$Nodes (.*)\$EndNodes')` and many others combinations of characters, but nothing seems to work.

What I need, in the end, is something like:

```
list_of_nodes = [('1', '0', '0', '0'), ('2', '1', '0', '0'), ('3', '1', '1', '0'), ('4', '0', '1', '0'), ('5', '0.5', '0.5', '0')]
```

Any help would be apreciated. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post the exact expected output. If you precise ther requirements, it will also help.

Comment: Done! Just updated the question with exactly what I need.

Comment: By the way, I still learning ReGex, so that post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870954/python-regular-expression-across-multiple-lines) is way too advanced for me..

Comment: You just need to read the beginning of the https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870990/3832970 answer. You can't achieve what you need with just one regex with Python `re`. You may get that with one regex using PyPi regex module.

Comment: I don't get it: do you only (and always) have a single block of `$Nodes...$EndNodes` inside a string? If yes, are there always numbers inside? Then, why use a regex here? Python `re` is not that efficient when it comes to complex text parsing. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/uL5huS).

Comment: Because I am using this problem to learn Regular expressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close. The regex you wrote would work with the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag. In regex, `.` represents 'any character except newline'. When you use the `re.DOTALL` flag, `.` includes the newlines as well.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2dSwLP/1)

Comment: yes, it workd! Thank you! But what if I need to read the three floating characters? Is there any /f or /f6.5 (as in C printf)?

Comment: You could just pick up a line and use the `split()` method on that, i.e. `[float(x) for x in line.split()]` will give you a list of numbers in `line`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want single numbers, as the number five (second lin) for exemple. I thoght about something like '(\d{3, })'...

Comment: How about `[float(x) for x in line.split() if '.' in x]`?

Comment: Hmmm... No. It will get just line 7. All other numbers are represented as integers...

Comment: Oh, got it. I think `[float(x) for x in line.split() if len(line.split()) > 1]` should do it. I thought you wanted only the numbers with a `.` in them. The `> 1` can be replaced by `>= 3` according to your question.

Comment: But won't it fail when trying to convert a blank character or a \n character?

Comment: It won't, I think. The `split()` method would take all the whitespace characters away.

Comment: So I guess it should be better if I do line2 = line.split('\n') first?

Comment: If you want to get a list of the lines, yes.

Comment: But I still would like to solve it using RegEx...