# regexp for multiline in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regexp, was wondering how to fetch the 3rd column values when the content of the column is not similar always

O/P picture in the link for better understanding

[image]

sw1-tb100# sh mod

Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status

---

1    34     1/10/40G IPS,2/4/8/10/16G FC Module DS-X9334-K9        ok

2    48     1/10 Gbps Ethernet Module           DS-X9848-480K9     ok

5    0      Supervisor Module-3                 DS-X97-SF1-K9      active *

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the txt format of the table.

```
re.findall("(\d{1,2}?) +(\d{1,2}?) +(.*?) +(.+?\s\w+\w+?) +(.*\-?) +(\w+)", "your_input_file")
```

The above will match your first 2 rows:

```
==========================================================
1 34 1/10/40G IPS,2/4/8/10/16G FC Module DS-X9334-K9 ok

2 48 1/10 Gbps Ethernet Module DS-X9848-480K9 ok
==========================================================
```

Also you can refer the below link

[python regular expression across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870954/python-regular-expression-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But 3rd column values have space. the regexp will break that as different value

Comment: >>> a = "1    34     1/10/40G IPS,2/4/8/10/16G FC Module DS-X9334-K9 ok"
>>> re.findall("(\d{1,2}?) +(\d{1,2}?) +(.*?) +(.+?\s\w+\w+?) +(.*\-?) +(\w+)", a)
[('1', '34', '1/10/40G', 'IPS,2/4/8/10/16G FC', 'Module DS-X9334-K9', 'ok')]
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regexp, you can try the following with simple string split operation.

```
line = "1 34 1/10/40G IPS,2/4/8/10/16G FC Module DS-X9334-K9 ok"
print " ".join(line.split()[2:-2])
```

You can put this in a loop to repeat it for all the lines.

Edit 1:

You may use either of the following to remove problem with asterisks. Then again, you may need to tweak it if you have additional special cases in logs.

```
print " ".join(str2.replace("*","").split()[2:-2])
print " ".join(str2.split("DS")[0].split()[2:])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works for first  3 lines.
One problem with this sometimes the line will end with asterisk (line 4 here) making at as one column extra for that line it will fail to split

>>> line = "5    0      Supervisor Module-3                 DS-X97-SF1-K9      active *"
>>> print " ".join(line.split()[2:-2])
Supervisor Module-3 DS-X97-SF1-K9

Comment: I can see a number of ways to fix this. You can do a replace operation to remove asterisks or you can split with " DS-" as 4th column seems to be always starting with "DS-". You may need to tweak it a little bit, as I don't have the complete log output.